# base64 Image Cached?

Tags: caching, base64

I have an image encoded in base64 and in an HTML page.

Example:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4S/+...">
```

Simple question:

Is the above code cached or is it loaded every time the page loads? I find conflicting answers when I research the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "the above code cached" you mean if the image is decoded each time or if the browser keeps a decoded image cache in memory? If so, to me the answer is no, it won't keep the decoded image, only the data to decode the image again (the whole HTML in this case). Maybe I'm wrong, but that's what I will expect.